# ListView shows empty message briefly before data is loaded

Tags: android, android-listfragment

I've created a `ListFragment` using the following custom layout which adds a `TextView` to show a message when the list is empty:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

  <ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>

  <TextView android:id="@id/android:empty"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/vsl_empty"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#8C8C8C" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The data is loaded using a custom adapter that derives from `CursorAdapter`. When there is data in the database, the list very briefly shows the empty list message until the data is loaded, at which point the list gets populated.

How can I prevent the empty list message from briefly appearing because the list hasn't been populated yet?

**Update**

I want to emphasise that I'm using a `ListFragment` with a layout that contains a `ListView` with the special id `android:list`, and a `TextView` with the special id `android:empty`, as explained [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html).

Setting `android:visibility="invisible"` doesn't affect the visibility. I suspect this is because it gets set to visible internally.

Comment: Are you using `Loader`s?

Comment: Yes. I create the adapter with `null` for the cursor argument, set the adapter on the `ListView` and then init the loader. The LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks take care of creating the cursor.

Answer (score 9):

The provided answers were on the right track. I indeed had to set the `TextView` to invisible, but the correct location is in `onCreateLoader`:

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args)
{
  mListView.getEmptyView().setVisibility(ListView.GONE);

  return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
}
```

Also, it's not necessary to make the empty view visible again: this is done automatically by the framework.

Comment: Thanks this worked. I had to make the empty view visible again using ListView.VISIBLE

Comment: You shouldn't need to make the LIST invisible (use a ViewSwitcher) for example.

Answer (score 1):

How about adding the following to the TextView

```
android:visibility="invisible"
```

to the XML layout file, and then making the TextView visible if required.

Comment: Setting the `TextView` to `invisible` makes no different.

Answer (score -1):

You will have to set the `TextView` *visibility* to *invisible*, and only once you have loaded the data --that is `onLoadComplete`-- you will have to set it as the empty view for the `ListView` by doing `setEmptyView(textView)`;

If you do it in *XML* or you do it before your results are loaded, the view will be shown since the list is effectively empty. So you have to wait until the results are loaded to set the empty view.

Comment: How do I set the `TextView` to invisible? In the XML, using the id `android:empty`, setting it to invisible doesn't work. I'm guessing it's overridden because the id has a special meaning. What's super-weird is, if at the end of `onActivityCreated()` I call `setEmptyView(null);` the ListView disappears and **only** the empty view is shown!