# Empty Listview Text shows for a few seconds before listview loads

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview

Let me quickly state that there is a question similar to this here  [ListView shows empty message briefly before data is loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124326/listview-shows-empty-message-briefly-before-data-is-loaded)

But this uses a `ListFragment` and derives from `CursorAdapter`, while I am using an "ordinary" Fragment and my adapter derives from BaseAdapter.

I have set an empty textview to display when there is no data in the database, but the textview is shown briefly while the data loads.

[image]

In my Fragment, I have this code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    databaseManager = new DatabaseManager(getActivity());
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    mContext = getActivity();
}



public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list_layout, container, false);

    itemListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.itemListView);
    emptyText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.empty);        
    registerForContextMenu(itemListView);
    itemListView.setClickable(true);
    itemListView.setEmptyView(emptyText);
    ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setTitle("Items");
    }

    new ItemListLoadAsync().execute();

    return rootView;
}
```

In my derived BaseAdapter class, I have this:

```
 public class ItemViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

 @Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
}


@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return items.get(position);
}


@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
                mContext.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list_row, null);


    }

    itemNameTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemNameTextView);
    descriptionTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.descriptionTextView);


    itemNameTextView.setText(items.get(position).getItemName());
    descriptionTextView.setText(items.get(position).getItemDescription());

    return convertView;

}
```

How do I correct this? Am I using the "right" adapter for my list?

Comment: Set Visibility of `emptyTextview` to `Gone`

Comment: AFAIK You are using Custom Adapter. so there is no need to display emptyview while there is no data .There is way : you  can just put a condition in getView() when you set the Text in Textview ,if data is null setText("") else setText("yourData"). Your problem is occurs because you are doing itemListView.setEmptyView(emptyText); before AsyncTask is called!so It will going to show emptyView everytime before data set to Adapter.

Comment: This is correct (though maybe not intended) behavior. One thing `ListFragment` has that regular `Fragment` does not is a method `setListShown(boolean)`. It's common to call `setListShown(false)` very early (before the views are visible on screen), which makes a spinner show instead of the normal content. Then after the first load you call `setListShown(true)`, at which point either you'll see a list or the empty view. You could do something similar; perhaps have the empty TextView have no text at all, then set its text after the first load completes.

Answer (score 0):

You could call setEmptyView() later so you can determine whether or not there is data to load.

Comment: This line can be add as comment also!please be careful while posting such answers

Comment: Why, it's an answer that can resolve his problem? Is that not what we do here?

Comment: AFAIK this is not proper way to give Answer. I am not going to down vote this but may be someone probably do it !

Comment: So you don't know the correct way to give an answer but your telling me I'm doing it wrong... I honestly don't know how to reply to that.

Comment: @MDroid FWIW, I'd take your comment and make it an answer as well.  You might still need to use comments to ask for further clarification, but I'd say an answer is an answer regardless of the length.  The fact that an answer is short enough to fit in a comment doesn't require it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @MDroid's comment, I removed the line:

```
itemListView.setEmptyView(emptyText);
```

and then in the onPostExecute() method of my `ItemListAsyncTask`, I did this:

```
public void onPostExecute(List<Item> items) {
        long delayInMillis = 500;
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }, delayInMillis);


        if(items.size() == 0) {
            itemListView.setEmptyView(emptyText);
        } else {
            ItemViewAdapter = new ItemViewAdapter(mContext, items);
            itemListView.setAdapter(itemViewAdapter);
        }

    }
```